# How To Defrag Windows 8 System Reserved Partition

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, defragment, system-reserved-partition

Today I was cleaning up my computer and stuff and when I was defraging my partitions I saw that the `System Reserved` partition is 100% fragmented.

So I tried to defrag it, but it doesn't seems to work, the partition is still 100% fragmented.

Is this a bad thing for the computer? How much will this affect the performance of the computer and how can I defrag this partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to defragment that volume. It is more likely the defrag program you are using is not using the correct permissions, and not able to tell the level of fragmentation accurately. When Windows is installed, it copies these files to the partition in such a way that they should not be fragmented.

It contains the boot manager and its language files, as well as memtest. The actual data loaded from the volume is about 1MB. If it was fragmented, the performance drop would be minimal, most likely undetectable.

Comment: I'm using the default windows disk defragment. If I install a defragment program and try to defrag it, will this cause any problems/malfunctions ?

Comment: @Chun I would use a different program just to get a read on the level of fragmentation, it is likely there is none.